# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"schools"} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't know why I couldn't create an info link for every school in my project. Here is the full error:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"schools"} missing
>   required keys: [:id]  <%= link_to "Info", school_path, class: "btn
>   btn-info" %>

Here is my index.html.erb:

```
    <% @schools.each do |school| %>
      <%= school.name %>
      <%= link_to "Info", school_path, class: "btn btn-info" %>
      <br>
    <% end %>
```

schools_controller.rb:

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @school = School.new
  end

  def edit
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @schools = School.all
  end

  def create
    @school = School.new(school_params)

    @school.save
    redirect_to @school
  end

  private

    def school_params
      params.require(:school).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need pass school object or school id to school_path method. So it can create a path by that id. You can do it as following;

```
<% @schools.each do |school| %>
  <%= school.name %>
  <%= link_to "Info", school_path(school), class: "btn btn-info" %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am following the tutorial at http://guides.rubyonrails.org, and trying to figure it out things for my project. Have a good day sir.

Comment: Alright, I will do it, it said I need to wait for 4 mins. Thanks again sir.

Comment: You can also use `<%= link_to "Info", school, class: "..." %>`

Answer (score 4):

Because you're learning, I'll give you some context.

--

> No route matches

The error means your [Rails routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-purpose-of-the-rails-router) could not find the referenced route you had.

It gives the following specification:

> missing required keys: [:id]

This means that the route *exists*, but you've not filled out the `id` parameter.

--

To help you understand how this works, consider the [following](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions):

```
   GET          /photos             photos#index    display a list of all photos
   GET          /photos/new         photos#new      return an HTML form for creating a new photo
   POST         /photos             photos#create   create a new photo
>> GET          /photos/:id         photos#show     display a specific photo
   GET          /photos/:id/edit    photos#edit     return an HTML form for editing a photo
   PATCH/PUT    /photos/:id         photos#update   update a specific photo
   DELETE       /photos/:id         photos#destroy  delete a specific photo
```

These are the *routes* created from using the `resources` directive in Rails. I won't explain about it right now - just saying that when you call `school_path`, you're referring to the `GET /schools/:id` path in your routes.

As such, what you have to remember is that when you invoke this route, you have to send an `id` to it -- `url.com/schools/1`. This allows the controller to look up the appropriate record (`School.find params[:id]`).

When you call...

```
<%= link_to "Info", school_path, class: "btn btn-info" %>
```

... you're not passing any param to `school_path`.

To fix it, you have to pass the `id`, which Rails will do automatically if you pass the appropriate object:

```
<%= link_to "Info", school_path(school), class: ".." %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "Info", school, class: "..." %>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Peck for your helpful answer. Have a nice day.