# How to pass in extra params in RSpec Rails request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, parameters, request

I'm still a beginner so what I am trying to do is probably not optimal, feel free to suggest a better method:

I am trying to test creating a contract for an associated user. The user and authenticate_user method are to be stubbed, however RSpec is saying it's not seeing the user_id foreign key in the params I'm passing in inside of :contract_params. Can someone please tell me of a way to pass in user_id so that RSpec would recognize it? 
Thank you!

[image]

spec/requests/contracts_api_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe "ContractsApi", type: :request do

  describe "POST #create" do
    let (:contract_params) do
      {
        user: {
          vendor: "Lebara",
          starts_on: "2018-12-12",
          ends_on: "2018-12-16",
          price: "15",
          user_id: "8"
        }
      }
    end
    before(:each) do
      controller.stub(:authenticate_user)
    end

    it 'creates a new contract' do
      expect { post api_v1_user_contracts_path, params: contract_params }.to change(Contract, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/api/v1/contracts_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::ContractsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user

  def create
    contract = @current_user.contracts.build(contract_params)
    if contract.save
      render json: contract
    else
      render json: contract.errors
    end
  end

  private

  def contract_params
    params.require(:contract).permit(:vendor, :starts_on, :ends_on, :price)
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading [No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"schools"} missing required keys: [:id]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718874/no-route-matches-action-show-controller-schools-missing-required-keys?rq=1) I realized that the user_id needed to be appended to the url path, thus I was successful by making the following changes:

```
describe "POST #create" do
    let (:contract_params) do
      {
        vendor: "Lebara",
        starts_on: "2018-12-12",
        ends_on: "2018-12-16",
        price: "15",
      }
    end
    before(:each) do
      @user = User.create(full_name: "Jason Bourne", email: "jbourne@test.com", password: "123456")
      controller.stub(:authenticate_user)
    end

    it 'creates a new contract' do
      expect { post api_v1_user_contracts_path(@user), params: contract_params }.to change(Contract, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```